# Sinatra Title Slugs

Tags: ruby, sinatra, helper, slug

I'm trying to create a slug helper in Sinatra. Here's the code (as seen [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2384)):

```
helpers do
  def sluggify(title)
  accents = { 
    ['á','à','â','ä','ã'] => 'a',
    ['Ã','Ä','Â','À'] => 'A',
    ['é','è','ê','ë'] => 'e',
    ['Ë','É','È','Ê'] => 'E',
    ['í','ì','î','ï'] => 'i',
    ['Î','Ì'] => 'I',
    ['ó','ò','ô','ö','õ'] => 'o',
    ['Õ','Ö','Ô','Ò','Ó'] => 'O',
    ['ú','ù','û','ü'] => 'u',
    ['Ú','Û','Ù','Ü'] => 'U',
    ['ç'] => 'c', ['Ç'] => 'C',
    ['ñ'] => 'n', ['Ñ'] => 'N'
  }

  accents.each do |ac,rep|
    ac.each do |s|
      title = title.gsub(s, rep)
    end
  end

  title = title.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/,"")
  title = title.gsub(/[ ]+/," ")    
  title = title.gsub(/ /,"-")
  title = title.downcase

end

end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass
```

What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: sinatra tag should be removed. this is a ruby problem, not sinatra problem.

Answer (score 1):

"What exactly is going wrong?"

Well, the error message is kinda self-explanatory. You called this method with title variable set to *nil*. To reproduce the error, try calling:

```
slugify(nil)
```

I suppose that it failed on this line:

```
title = title.gsub(s, rep)
```

To avoid this, you can either check for *nil* title at the beginning of the method:

```
raise "wrong input!" if title.nil?
```

or (IMHO more elegant) always convert title to string, which converts eventual *nil* to empty string:

```
title = title.to_s # "any string" => "any string", nil => ""
```

---

BTW your code could use some serious refactoring. For a start, try replacing:

```
title = title.gsub(/a/,/b/)
```

with

```
title.gsub!(/a/,/b/)
```

or use [tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000830) method instead of *gsub* for character-to_character replacement:

```
"woot".tr("wt","WT") # => "WooT"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to duplicate what you're seeing. Here's my test (outside of Sinatra, so just using a module):

```
module Helpers
  def self.sluggify(title)
    accents = {['á','à','â','ä','ã'] => 'a'} # Shortened

    accents.each do |ac,rep|
      ac.each do |s|
        title = title.gsub(s, rep)
      end
    end

    title = title.gsub(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/,"")
    title = title.gsub(/[ ]+/," ")    
    title = title.gsub(/ /,"-")
    title = title.downcase
  end
end

puts Helpers.sluggify("Testing this!")
```

Yields `testing-this`.

Comment: I have the source on GitHub if you want to try it: http://github.com/eturk/marvin

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at iconv's transliteration ability. It will let you avoid building your own table of character conversions.

Obie Fernandez to the rescue: http://www.jroller.com/obie/tags/unicode

Comment: Yes, but how exactly do I make that into a Sinatra helper?